# Combine and Manipulate two columns as Date using PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an csv file and reading it through pandas:

```
cols=['DATE(GMT)','TIME(GMT)',DATASET]
df=pd.read_csv('datasets.csv', usecols=cols)
```

csv file content are as follows:

```
DATE(GMT)   TIME(GMT)   DATASET
05-01-2018     0          10
05-01-2018     1          15
05-01-2018     2          21
05-01-2018     3          9
05-01-2018     4          25
05-01-2018     5          7
   ...        ...        ...
05-02-2018     14         65
```

Now I need to combine 'DATE(GMT)','TIME(GMT)' as a single DateTime column. So that I can have only two columns i.e. DATETIME and DATASET

Comment: `df['DATETIME '] = df['DATE(GMT)'].astype(str) + " " +df['TIME(GMT)'].astype(str)`?

Comment: `TIME(GMT)` column is in `hour`s ? Or `second`s?

Comment: Its hours only,

Comment: @Rakesh: It works but then it gives '05-01-2018 2' like string how to convert them in standard date format. dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameter `parse_dates` to `red_csv` for `datetime` column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('datasets.csv', usecols=cols, parse_dates=['DATE(GMT)'])

print (df.dtypes)
DATE(GMT)    datetime64[ns]
TIME(GMT)             int64
DATASET               int64
dtype: object
```

And then add Time column converted [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['DATE(GMT)'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('TIME(GMT)').astype(str), unit='H')
print (df)
            DATE(GMT)  DATASET
0 2018-05-01 00:00:00       10
1 2018-05-01 01:00:00       15
2 2018-05-01 02:00:00       21
3 2018-05-01 03:00:00        9
4 2018-05-01 04:00:00       25
5 2018-05-01 05:00:00        7
6 2018-05-02 14:00:00       65
```

EDIT:

There is problem some data are non numeric:

```
print (df)
    DATE(GMT) TIME(GMT)  DATASET
0  05-01-2018         0       10
1  05-01-2018         1       15
2  05-01-2018         2       21
3  05-01-2018         3        9
4  05-01-2018         4       25
5  05-01-2018         s        7
6  05-02-2018         a       65
```

You can find it:

```
print (df[pd.to_numeric(df['TIME(GMT)'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
    DATE(GMT) TIME(GMT)  DATASET
5  05-01-2018         s        7
6  05-02-2018         a       65
```

And then if need repalce it by `0` (with all missing values):

```
df['TIME(GMT)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TIME(GMT)'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
print (df)
    DATE(GMT)  TIME(GMT)  DATASET
0  05-01-2018        0.0       10
1  05-01-2018        1.0       15
2  05-01-2018        2.0       21
3  05-01-2018        3.0        9
4  05-01-2018        4.0       25
5  05-01-2018        0.0        7
6  05-02-2018        0.0       65
```

Comment: I got this error while trying this: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('S12') nad dtype('<m8[ns]')

Comment: @utyagi - Please check eited answer.

Comment: Thanks!; They are:
DATE(GMT)          object
TIME(GMT)           int64
DATASET               float64